# Switch Excel Function

Tags: excel

I have a question about functions in Excel (2016).

I need to change the formula depending on the value of the cell. This can be achieved by nesting IF functions.

[image]

But there is a problem. The problem is that it becomes difficult to see which cells are the actual targets of the calculation.

Sometimes we want to check which cells are the target of the calculation.

If the result column contains formula for Condition A (in this case, the multiplication of two cells), the cells to be calculated can be highlighted by editing the cell, and the target of the calculation can be easily checked.

[image]

However, in the case of nested IF functions, all cells are highlighted, and it is not immediately clear which cell is the real target of the calculation.

[image]

For example, is it possible to rewrite the function itself in the result column according to the value in the condition column?

Comment: Split the calculation into parts to understand, if(logical test, value if true, value if false). Or create a list and use vlookup().

Comment: Why not just add conditional formatting to highlight the prerequisite cells based on the condition? that way you don't need to interrogate the formula and the data is always highlighted.